# How to have a class in a namespace that has the same name that is part of another namespace in a .net class library

Tags: .net, namespaces, class-library

ok...this gets confusing for me to explain, so i will show a class from one namespace and a seperate namespace...

`Company.Product.Domain` 
(this represents the class that contains methods specific to that class, i named it "Domain" just so you can see how I'm using the same name in a separate namespace

`Company.Product.Domain.Data.Contracts`
(this namespace will be for all of the data contracts to be used in a WCF service)

If I am in the `Company.Product.Domain` class and I try to use the classes within `Company.Product.Domain.Data.Contracts`, when I attempt to type this out, i get to `Company.Product.Domain` and will not show intellisense any further.  It also shows that that reference is a class instead of allowing me to get to the namespace.

I do have the `Company.Product.Domain.Data.Contracts` referenced in my `Company.Product.Domain` class.

Is it possible to have a namespace `Company.Product` with a class inside of it and also another namespace of `Company.Product.Domain.Data.Contracts`?  If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. However, you should avoid it like the plague. It makes everything *much* more complicated.

Eric Lippert has written a series of blog posts on this very topic recently. Admittedly it's not *quite* the same issue - he's talking about `Foo.Bar.Bar` (where `Foo.Bar` is the namespace, and `Bar` is the class) but I believe you'll run into many of the same issues. Indeed, I think you may actually end up making them *worse* than the scenario he's describing. Please don't do it.

- [Part One: Collisions amongst referenced assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)
- [Part Two: Machine-generated code](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/11/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two.aspx)
- [Part Three: Bad hierarchical design](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/15/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three.aspx)
- [Part Four: Making the problem worse](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/18/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four.aspx)

Comment: I actually went the route that I did to avoid the "double name" issue.  Instead of Company.Product.Domain.Domain, i went with the route of separating the class from the namespace.  So in the case of creating my second namespace, i wanted the rest of the data to be in the same path as my class so that the flow to the developers that used it would be the same.  Also the class structures would live in the same path in the class libraries.  I will read these, but the reason i'm doing what i'm doing is to avoid just what you said foo.bar.bar

Comment: @dwhittenburg: But why introduce more ambiguity? If you call it `Company.Product.Domain.DomainHelper` or something like that, there'll be no ambiguity at all, and you won't need to fight against the language.

Comment: I understand that, it just seems like a work-around rather than being able to structure the library in a logical structure.  Also, I try to stay away from "Helper" objects, etc and put the objects in the correct structure with a correct naming convention.  And the main thing is why can't .NET differentiate between a class and a namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You can **alias** your Company.Product.Domain.Data namespace.

So in your Domain class, instead of

```
using Company.Product.Domain.Data;
```

try something like

```
using myData = Company.Product.Domain.Data;
namespace Company.Product
{
  class Domain
  { ...
    myData::Data.method();
  }
}
```

I'm not positive that intellisense behaves the way you want with this, but it does disambiguate the Domain class vs. Domain namespace.